# Can we make a separate instance of portlet?

Tags: liferay

I have a liferay instance on 8080. In that I have nearly 80 portlets which I am using for my application.

In that one portlet for example portlet A is used more. Means the requests to A will be huge based on the number of users. Which slows downs the other process of requests to other portlets.

So I thought of implementing the portlet A in another liferay instance with different port suppose 8181.

Now when I login through first instance and clicked on a page which should redirect to port 8181 liferay instance (Probably separate thread) from 8080.

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Question is not clear. Can you give some example or elaborate? What do you mean by have "portlets in my liferay instance". And what do you mean by having a separate instance for that one portlet?

Comment: @PrakashK editted the question and made it brief. Have a look now.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is currently in development and expected to be released on marketplace soon. If the wording did not change, look for "resiliency" (just not today, but in future).

Your current options would be to utilize WSRP with a secondary portal. Or, of course, implement your resource-hungry portlet as a very shallow implementation that accesses an external implementation, e.g. through standard Webservices.

Comment: is this possible?  <rule>
        <from>^/web/pushnotification(.*)$</from>
       <to type="permanent-redirect">http://localhost:8181$1</to>
    </rule> as per the link http://www.gmedi.org/web/anishmusa/publication/-/blogs/url-rewrite-in-liferay